# How can I run theano on GPU

Tags: python, cuda, gpu, theano

If I run the following code with python 3.5

```
import numpy as np
import time
import theano
A = np.random.rand(1000,10000).astype(theano.config.floatX)
B = np.random.rand(10000,1000).astype(theano.config.floatX)
np_start = time.time()
AB = A.dot(B)
np_end = time.time()
X,Y = theano.tensor.matrices('XY')
mf = theano.function([X,Y],X.dot(Y))
t_start = time.time()
tAB = mf(A,B)
t_end = time.time()
print ("NP time: %f[s], theano time: %f[s] **(times should be close when run
on CPU!)**" %(np_end-np_start, t_end-t_start))
print ("Result difference: %f" % (np.abs(AB-tAB).max(), ))
```

I get the output

```
NP time: 0.161123[s], theano time: 0.167119[s] (times should be close when
run on CPU!)
Result difference: 0.000000
```

it says if the times are close, it means that I am running on my CPU.

How can I run this code on my GPU?

**NOTE:**

- I have a workstation with Nvidia Quadro k4200.
- I have installed Cuda toolkit
- I have successfully worked an cuda vectorAdd sample project on VS2012.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You configure Theano to use a GPU by specifying the `device=gpu` in Theano's config. There are two principle methods for setting the config: (1) in the `THEANO_FLAGS` environment variable, or (2) via the .theanorc file. Both methods, and all of Theano's configuration flags, are [documented](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/config.html).

You will know that Theano is using the GPU if, after calling `import theano` you see a message that looks something like this

```
Using gpu device 0: GeForce GT 640 (CNMeM is disabled)
```

The details may vary for you but if no message appears at all then Theano is using the CPU only.

Note also that even if you see the GPU message, your particular computation graph may not run on the GPU. To see which parts of your computation are running on the GPU print its compiled and optimized graph

```
f = theano.function(...)
theano.printing.debugprint(f)
```

Operations that start with the prefix 'Gpu' will run on the GPU. Operations that do not have that prefix to their name will run on the CPU.

Comment: thanks. but in my environment variables, there is no variable about theano. 
the document say a file call .theanorc, in my home directory, the file is absent. how i set "device" value ?

Comment: If `THEANO_FLAGS` doesn't exist, create it!

Comment: `import theano`
`device='gpu0'` 
check device value 
`print(theano.config.device)`
it is 'cpu' again.

Comment: how i create this flags ?

Comment: Depends on your operating system. For Windows, try https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/sysdm_advancd_environmnt_addchange_variable.mspx?mfr=true. For Linux, try https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-read-and-set-environmental-and-shell-variables-on-a-linux-vps

Comment: You (generally) can't change the device after `import theano`. You need to set device=gpu in either THEANO_FLAGS environment variable, or in the .theanorc file.

Comment: I know the location of environment variables. but i didn't understand what i add to env. variables for flag ?? 
 I create a file .theanorc and add to flag in txt file. when i run `import theano`. , it gives several error :(

Comment: The documentation I linked to in my answer explains what to put in the environment variable value.

Answer (score 7):

If you are on Linux, create a .theanorc file in your home folder and add the following to set up theano to run on GPU.

```
[global]
device = gpu
floatx = float32
```

Comment: just a detail. it's float32, not floar32 (typo). I cannot edit it :-(

Comment: for version 1.0.4; device=cuda

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively, if you want to use the GPU programattically:

```
import theano.sandbox.cuda
theano.sandbox.cuda.use("gpu0")
```

You should see a message like this:

```
Using gpu device 0: Tesla K80
```

Useful if the environment you are running in isn't easy to configure.

Comment: This works for theano v0.9. and it is now deprecated.
`You are importing theano.sandbox.cuda. This is the old GPU back-end and is removed from Theano. Use Theano 0.9 to use it. Even better, transition to the new GPU back-end! See https://github.com/Theano/Theano/wiki/Converting-to-the-new-gpu-back-end%28gpuarray%29
`